# Find lines with only 7 letters or numbers

Tags: notepad++

I'm using Notepad++,and I have a document with 88,000 lines.

I need the lines with only 7 letters or numbers.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

- Go to **Search → Find**
- In the *Find What* textbox paste the following:

  > ^\w\w\w\w\w\w\w$
- Ensure that *Search Mode* is set to *Regular expression*
- Click **Find All in Current Document**

[image: Notepad++ screenshot]

Each `\w` indicates an occurence of a letter or number and the `^` and the `$` indicate that these must be matched between the start and end of a line.

Comment: Wouldn't a easier to read version be `^\w{7}$`? (I'm not sure if Notepad++ supports that syntax, but it is hardly unheard of.)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: For whatever reason, I couldn't get it to work using that shorthand. Presumably NotePad++ doesn't support it.

Comment: its nt supporting

Comment: @abusamra: Can you be a bit more specific about why it's not working? Do you not get any matches at all? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: @James, make sure you've updated Notepad++. Version 6 includes PCRE, and it supports `^\w{7}$`

Answer (score 0):

Go to find, select Regular Expressions and then type

```
.......\r\n
```

`.` stands for any character, so 7× `.` is amount of chars, `\r\n` is the newline character. Depending on your OS, you might have to use something different like:

- Windows: `\r\n`
- Linux: `\n`
- Mac: `\r`

Comment: its not working properly.

Comment: This would match any line with seven or more characters.